# How does hybrid median filter work at edges?

Tags: image, image-processing

Want to implement Hybrid median filter . How does operation of Hybrid median filter and how does working change at edges and how is it preserving the Edges?

Comment: Could you please give a clear definition of the filter? I think I've seen the term hybrid filter used for a number of different methods in the past.

Comment: Do you possibly mean a bilateral filter, which is edge aware?